# FlashDevelop/OpenFL: How to set default target to neko

Tags: haxe, openfl

I am trying to write some cross-language code with Haxe/OpenFL and compile it using FalshDevelop. But I get an error as soon as I use the basic `Sys.print` function. A minimal example is as follows:

```
package;

import flash.display.Sprite;

class Graphic extends Sprite {


    public function new () {
        super ();
    }

    static function main() { //used in standalone swf project
        Sys.print("Hi");
        }
}
```

It turns out that the default compile command of FlashDevelop is something like:

```
haxelib run openfl build project.xml flash
```

,which gives an error on `Sys.print`:

```
Graphic.hx:xx: characters 2-11 : Accessing this field requires a system platform
 (php,neko,cpp,etc.)
```

My guess is that `Sys.print` isn't available in the flash target or flash isn't `a system platform` (strange). I was wondering if there is way to work around this, and configure FlashDevelop so that the compile command is:

> haxelib run openfl build project.xml **neko**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually 2 questions.

For the first one, Sys.print is available only on some platforms because it wouldn't make sense in others(what would it do in flash?), what you probably want is trace, which is used to print things for debug purposes.

For the second question there is a drop down menu at the top of flashdevelop if you created a openfl project that looks like this and does exactly that:

[image: drop down menu in flashdevelop]

Comment: Thanks for your answers (esp. the second one). Regarding the first, I don't think having a `Sys.print` in Flash is non-sense. You have `stdout` in many graphical programming languages/frameworks regardless of the fact that you don't see your output on the GUI. Dropping "Sys.print', however, gives you compile-time errors that forbids certain code to be cross-language. IMHO, not having `Sys.print` does more harm than good to a generic language like Haxe.

Comment: `trace` would be fine if it does not force you to print the file name, line number and `\n`.

Comment: Sys.print exists in the platforms that support it, in neko for example it outputs to the console from which you called the executable, as far as I know flash cannot output to stdout, so I see little if no point of having Sys.out on flash.

What do you want to do with Sys.out in flash?

Comment: There is actually a point in having stdout in Flash, if you are more interested in the ActionScript language. And people have been asking around about how to do this in SO for years: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651/any-way-to-have-an-actionscript-3-flex-air-project-print-to-standard-output http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056056/is-it-possible-to-create-a-command-line-swf?lq=1